# Getting null value on Autowired object in spring

Tags: spring

I have following bean XML and it is imported in ApplicationConfiguration.java and just created DbManager autowired in Test class but it is always getting null.
Can any one help out.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache 
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <bean id="dbManager" class="com.bandu.myfriendsbook.common.services.dbservices.dbmanager.impl.DbManagerImpl">

    </bean>

    <bean id="dbManagers"  class="java.util.ArrayList">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <ref bean="dbManager"/>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

and Configuration java file

```
@Configuration("applicationConfiguration")
@EnableSpringConfigured
@ComponentScan
@EnableCaching(mode = AdviceMode.PROXY, proxyTargetClass = true)
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true, mode = AdviceMode.PROXY)
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/app-spring-common-config.xml"})
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends CachingConfigurerSupport{

        //othere beans like datasource, cachemanager
}
```

Now just calling bean in ApplicationTest.java but it is getting always null.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private DbManagerImpl dbManager;

    public Integer testQuery(){
        return dbManager.testQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: @ComponentScan("my.package")?

Answer (score 2):

You must use @ComponentScan with parameter basePackages or basePackagesClasses.
Example:

```
 @ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `<context:annotation-config/>` to ur xml file to work @Autowired annotation.